# How to invert colors of a specific application, or window, only using Magnifier

Tags: windows-7, magnifier

The magnifier allows a user to invert the colors of the entire Desktop.

Does anyone know how to invert the colors of just an application, or a specific window?

Comment: do you want to be able to move your mouse while inverting? :)

Comment: Of course. Why do you ask this question?

Comment: because it's possible to achieve the window inversion effect with it if you don't move the mouse. may still be useful in some situations since it's a live view.

Comment: Build a virtual machine per application and run them in unity.

Comment: It's the kind of things that I always take for granted on Linux, and then I need to do it on Windows for somebody else and it's impossible.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: This uses a third party program. Not exactly what OP asked, but it's better than nothing.

There's a program called [Easy Invert](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Easy-Invert.shtml) and it can apply a number of color filters if the specified programs/windows are maximized, and **auto mode** is turned on.

By default, the program will apply the grayscale filter, but you can change it to Invert colors on the settings (Tray Icon -> Filter Type -> Invert)

The program is portable, and you have to left click it's icon on the tray area to set your settings. It has a key feature called **auto mode**. This feature will activate/deactivate the selected filters if any of the specified software (executable?) or windows is maximized.

Just note that for the program to work you need to have Windows 10 >= Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

and for all the paranoid users out there, [it has 0/69 detections on Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f40653a17ffe1fe3caaa5e9d3cd6edff0638f8f6ceed19da0c1cdbbb1c74e7f7/community)

Lastly, WARNING FOR EPILEPTIC USERS: Since the program takes some miliseconds to apply the color filters, the rapid color changes *might* trigger your condition. You've been warned.

Comment: Great application, you can trigger the invertion on an application path or window name. But it inverts the entire desktop, not only an application or a window. Thanks for letting me discover it but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Anti-malware software gave me an alert on this one...

Comment: Which "anti-malware" gave you an alert, and what was the alert? All 70 anti-virus that scanned the file on virustotal gave it a pass. The scanner you've installed isn't on vt, so I would question its accuracy

Comment: This does not invert a single application like the question requires, it applies it to the whole screen, even though it can be set to only turn on when the program is open.

Answer (score 5):

There are only three modes that Magnifier works in, and the high contrast colour inversion only works in conjunction with these modes. These modes are listed in the Microsoft page [Make items on the screen appear bigger (Magnifier)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/make-screen-items-bigger-magnifier#1TC=windows-7):

> There are three Magnifier modes:
>
> - Full-screen mode. In full-screen mode, your entire screen is    magnified. Depending on the size of your screen and the zoom level you choose, you might not be able to see all of the screen at the same time.
> - Lens mode. In lens mode, the area around the mouse pointer is    magnified. When you move the mouse pointer, the area of the screen that's magnified moves along with it.
> - Docked mode. In docked mode, only a portion of the screen is    magnified, leaving the rest of your desktop unchanged. You can then control which area of the screen is magnified.

So to achieve what you require, you will have to use in *Docked mode*, specifying a region occupied by a window (adjust the window to your particular tastes beforehand).  Unfortunately you can not thereafter move the window and expect the magnifier to follow it, but you can always "re-dock" the magnifier to the new window position. Not ideal, but better than nothing.

This is the manner in which I use it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the Docked mode doesn't match my needs, this mode inverts colours on a specific area but still follows the cursor. I want to invert colours on chosen windows.

Answer (score 2):

windows+"+" ==> ctrl+alt+f ==>ctrl+alt+I
that's pretty close to what you want but, it ivert the whole screen color, back to normal mode just close the magnifer or press ctrl+alt+I again

Comment: That hasn't worked for me, did open magnifier and activated it but in color inversion happened and I couldn't find any settings for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try WindowTop. Its Dark-Mode feature does exactly what you wanted (I mean EXACTLY). This feature requires a license, but you get a free evaluation period.

Links

- https://windowtop.info/
- https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windowtop/9PG6GHB4CT57