# How to invert colors of a specific application, or monitor on multi-monitor setup?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, colors, magnifier

As in topic.
How to invert colors of a specific application, or monitor?
Windows magnifier inverts colors on whole desktop.

This article: [How to invert colors of a specific application, or window, only using Magnifier](https://superuser.com/questions/341227/how-to-invert-colors-of-a-specific-application-or-window-only-using-magnifier) does not answer my question.

Comment: This actually two questions, only one of which appears to be a duplicate. 1. How to invert colors for an application; 2. How to invert colors on a specific monitor. #1 is answered, #2 is not.